# 1970s/1980s children's/YA show with unseen aliens interacting through people given special powers

Tags: story-identification, tv

This was a live-action SF show I saw during my childhood in the early 1980s, so it could be a repeat from the 1970s.  It was on UK TV, but that doesn't necessarily mean its a UK production.

The (unfortunately few) points I can remember are:

1. Radio telescopes were a central plot point, including several shots of large Jodrell Bank style ones
2. The aliens were never seen, but interacted through people by giving them powers and influencing their behaviour
3. People were given special powers such as telekinesis, and they could combine powers with another person by joining hands above their heads
4. In at least one episode, much was made of someone making a model which represented the aliens' influence - this model consisted of a number of spheres and pyramids on a flat base.  This model was destroyed by another character when they found out this person was under the alien influence.

Comment: I assume you've already ruled out *Quatermass*, the TV Serial about aliens influencing the "Planet People" and Professor Quatermass investigating?

Comment: It definitely wasn't a Quatermass serial, it was definitely more a YA or Sunday evening style SF show.

Comment: I think I remember what you are talking about.  I remember seeing bits and pieces of this show on PBS in the early 80's.  It was live action.

Comment: Congratulations on one of the most pointless closes of all time - 5 years after the last activity, and its being closed in favour of a question which has no accepted answer…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you by any chance thinking of [*Chocky*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocky_(TV_series))?

There were three series made; the first was 1984, so it fits with your timeline.

My memories of it are somewhat hazy, but it all seems to be on YouTube. This is from season 2 (1985, according to Wikipedia)

If you start at 24:00 you can see someone smashing a model that is made up of spheres and pyramids on a flat base.

I know Chocky was invisible, and that the kids got special powers from him, though I can't remember what powers. I've no idea whether there are radio telescopes involved, though.

Comment: Thats it, thats the show :)

Comment: Sounds kind of neat. Has a 7.9 on IMDB, although there are less than 200 ratings. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0202722/

Comment: I think 200 ratings on an obscure UK kids show from the 80's is pretty good

Comment: The radio telescopes were in the later series, "Chocky's Challenge".

Answer (score 2):

If there was a village set among prehistoric standing stones the show was probably *[Children of the Stones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_the_Stones)* (1977).

> The series followed the adventures of astrophysicist Adam Brake and his young son Matthew after they arrive in the small village of Milbury, which is built in the midst of a megalithic stone circle.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a stretch, since it's definitely more adult than a kid's show, but *[Quatermass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quatermass_(TV_serial_and_film))* (1979) was a TV serial, sometimes known as the *Quatermass Conclusion* or *Quatermass IV*. Professor Quatermass is investigating a cult of "Planet People" who are gathering at prehistoric sites to be transported to other planets. A radio telescope is constructed and used by one of the scientists to track the aliens. I have not found any references to powers or to a model. Still, it's the closest match I've found so far.

[image: Radio telescope]

Comment: Im afraid that definitely wasn't it, the main characters were teenager-age and the radio telescope was much much bigger (I think the plot line around that was an attempt to break into its control room to send a signal).  Thanks for the answer tho!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's *Chocky's Children* the middle serial of the three

Whilst on holiday, Matthew Gore, central character of the first serial, meets Albertine, whom he realises is influenced by the same alien as himself. But when he tries to explain this to her, she thinks he is accusing her of plagiarism, gets angry and breaks off their budding friendship. Matthew gets upset and smashes up the clay model of Chocky's world which he has made under her influence.

IIRC the radio-telescopes figure in Series 3, when Albertine is somewhat older and has gained a scholarship to a top university.