# Children’s show from 80s or 90s with telepathic children and an alien appearing as a ball of light

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

Unfortunately I have very limited memories of this show, but it’s most likely either from the late '80s or early '90s. It’s a live action show, not animated.

I remember a group of kids interacting with an alien, which I remember as a ball of light. The children had a telepathic connection between themselves, and also with the alien. There was also some evil organization (as always) that wanted to capture the alien.

I remember one episode where the children are building different platonic shapes for some purpose. When they build a pyramid and one is partially inside it they’re like “hey why aren’t you answering to me?” and they realize the pyramid shape is blocking their telepathy.

I think the pyramid was supposed to be used to capture the alien by some evil people.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Where did you see this?  What language was it in?

Comment: @DavidW I believe it was in English, and I watched it in Finland so I assume it would’ve be broadcast there at some point

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suspect this was the 1984 [BBC adaptation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocky_(TV_series)) of John Wyndham's book *Chocky* (1968).

The first series followed a single boy, Matthew, who was communicating with the alien intelligence which was represented on-screen as a ball of light - see [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvTHoEICsWE) for example.

The subsequent two series, *Chocky's Children* and *Chocky's Challenge*, which I don't think were based on the book, involved more children - and apparently a military organisation that wanted to capture Chocky.

Comment: As per https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134093/identification-needed-of-1970s-1980s-childrens-ya-show, there is a model made with various shapes including a pyramid.

Comment: When looking at this it seems like the representation of the alien entity does look familiar, as a circly vortexy thing, and the voice does sound familiar. I will have to watch it and see if it is, but so far seems like it would be this one!

Comment: In the third series, Chocky's Challenge the children try to build an antimatter engine with help from the alien. In episode 5 they build a pyramid shape, and when they try to enter it blocks their telepathy.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like "Out of This World" (1987-1991). If the kids could stop time by touching the tips of their index fingers together, then this is the show.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092423/):

> The series revolves around Evie Ethel Garland, who is the daughter of Troy and Donna Garland. However, Troy is an alien from the planet Antereus. As a benefit of her half-alien parentage, Evie develops three powers as the series progresses. She can pause and un-pause time, "gleep" objects into existence, and can transport herself from one place to another. Troy is living on Antereus and is never seen, but Evie talks to him via a crystal cube. Evie is thirteen at the beginning of the series and lives with her mother in Marlowe, California. Visitors to the Garland home include Donna's brother Beano Froelich; the mayor Kyle Applegate, a former actor; Lindsey Selkirk, Evie's best friend; Chris Fuller, Evie's boyfriend; and Buzz, who tends to take things literally. Episodes usually revolve around Evie getting herself out of a situation that she has caused.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you confirm the appearance of the alien, possibly add some images from the show?  Any details you can add that tie this to the question will help.

Comment: My recollection is there was only one kid with this power in the show, and she *was* an alien, along with her family, but they all looked perfectly human.  (There may have been some others that showed up occasionally, but the regular cast was just the one girl and her parents with powers, and some normal human friends.)