# Children's TV series shown in the UK around the late 80s/early 90s

Tags: story-identification

I'd be really interested to find out if anyone else can remember a TV show which was shown in the UK, I would say it was late 80s or early 90s.  All I remember is that there was a pyramid shaped object in the room of a normal looking house, not huge, around the height of a child.  The only scene I really remember after all these years is one where other children returned to find the side of the pyramid was open and one of the children had gone into the pyramid and was now unconscious (I think).

Comment: Welcome! Can you remember what the pyramid looked like? It's colour? If it was lit up etc. And can you remember if it was British or e.g. North American or Australian. Literally any detail no matter how small can help with these questions in jogging someone's memory. It may also be helpful to edit the title to mention the pyramid as this may catch the attention of someone who remembers the show but might otherwise pass over the question.

Comment: It might be worth checking out Chocky https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocky_(TV_series) and its sequels. The John Wyndham book they are based on is near the top of my reading list so I don't want to investigate further right now to avoid spoilers but from what I know it may match and there is some talk of model pyramids.

Comment: Was there anything science fictional or fantastical about this pyramid and/or the nature in which the child is rendered unconscious (or anything else in the show)?

Comment: This does sound like *Chocky*, which was previously asked about [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/252459/children-s-show-from-80s-or-90s-with-telepathic-children-and-an-alien-appearing/252461) including a mention of a pyramid.

Comment: Angelo's spaceship in the opening titles of Mike and Angelo is notably pyramid shaped, but I don't think it's ever seen that way in Mike's room - Angelo just comes out of his wardrobe.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32621/sci-fi-drama-tv-series-about-telepathy-between-an-alien-and-a-boy (about the same series)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on what you describe this is almost certainly from an episode of Chocky's Challenge.

Broadcast on channel 3 in the UK in the 1980s. There were three series, Chocky, based on the John Wyndham Novel of the same name, Chocky's Children and then finally Chocky's Challenge

There is not a lot of information on line about this series but you can read a wikipedia article here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocky_(TV_series)

and there are several episodes of Chocky's Challenge on youtube. The pyramid object you mention can be seen in Chocky's Challenge episode 6 at the 2 minute mark, the scene with the unconscious person inside the pyramid appears towards the end of the episode at 22minutes.

Comment: This is exactly it, thank you so much! I'd forgotten the part where the adult closes the pyramid on him, that had quite a big effect on me as a child I think.