# 80’s TV programme featuring a pyramid with a dangerous energy source inside

Tags: story-identification, tv

This one has been bugging me for nigh-on 25 years, so I’m hoping someone here can finally put this one to bed for me. I remember very little about this 80’s TV programme that was on British TV (but the programme may have originally been UK/Australian/US/Canadian), and I’m trying to identify it.

In the scene I remember, there was a metal pyramid or similar structure inside a building -- I think a house -- and the pyramid was about the height of a person. In the middle was a dangerous energy source that nobody could touch. An adult woman was showing the pyramid to a child. She encouraged him to go inside, and he carefully went in and around the back of the energy source in amazement. Then, as he went to get-out, she shut the door and trapped him inside.

I have tried to find this episode and come-across *The Tomorrow People*, *The Girl From Tomorrow* and other similar programmes from that time, but I have so far drawn a blank with this one. Does this scene ring a bell with anyone? I’m beginning to think I’ve dreamt this scene-up!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall roughly what time of day this was aired at? Like, was this an after-school or Saturday morning show for kids? Or was it on later in the evening?

Comment: I would have said it was definitely an after-school programme. And I think it was episodic as I think the credits rolled after this scene.

Comment: Could it be one of the series of *Chocky*? As noted [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/252459/children-s-show-from-80s-or-90s-with-telepathic-children-and-an-alien-appearing/252461#252461) the third one involved a pyramid, although that was to block telepathy rather than as a power source.

Comment: That is astounding Dan! Thank you so much! I’ve just looked-up and watched ‘Chocky’s Challenge’ on YouTube and at the end of Series 3 Episode 5 there is a scene that almost identically matches it. My mind obviously added a little artistic licence in the intervening 25 years… Amazing stuff. Thank you so much for your suggestion! I can’t imagine there is anything else it can be as that scene is so similar to how I described it to be. Why I was watching such strange TV in the 80’s - probably because there were only three channels!! Mr Roseman - you are a legend. 

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32621/sci-fi-drama-tv-series-about-telepathy-between-an-alien-and-a-boy