# Scifi TV show about an AI from a spaceship, contacting different teenagers?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv, episode-identification, artificial-intelligence

I am searching for a 90s TV show. It is about a spaceship with an AI that contacts different teenagers each episode.
In one of them, the alien AI sends a message to a teenager asking

> What is the FBI?

to which the teenager replies

> It is like the Police

In another episode, a teenager has to assemble different pieces of a pyramid object to defeat a monster, sort of, by inserting the final object in the latter's belly.

Comment: [*Chocky's Challenge*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocky_(TV_series)) has an alien contacting various teenagers, and there's a pyramid involved, but it's a British show, so I doubt they would have mentioned the FBI.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134093/1970s-1980s-childrens-ya-show-with-unseen-aliens-interacting-through-people-giv mentions some of the details.

Comment: @Vikram Ballgobin - Did you actually watch this in the '90s, or more recently? If more recently, then when?

Comment: Was this on US TV? UK? Canada? Australia? Other?